# Jupyter Notebook Variables not loading suddenly in Visual Code

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have been using the Jupyter:Variables on Visual Code for a while and haven't changed anything, however, the variables are no longer loading. I have used to different laptops and they are both experiencing the same issue. The variable just gets stuck loading.

[Screenshot of variable window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaD4B.png)

Comment: Does it not work with all the variables in the `JUPYTER:VARIABLES` except the `FG_data`? And have you tried to reload the VSCode and try some simpler variables?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. It does not work with any variables, simple or complex. I managed to get one of the laptops to work by changing the version of Jupyter. However, this did not work on the other.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, and could not find someone who met the same problem likes you. Could you try to install an older version of `Jupyter Notebook`?

Comment: Could you Select: `Help` > `Toggle Developer Tools`  then open the `Console` panel to get the details of the `Data Viewer` display?

Comment: I have a lot of errors. I have no idea what they mean. I can't seem to attach a screenshot here. I will try to figure that out.

Comment: @Steven-MSFT - A friend of mine has had a look at it for me and solved the problem. It seems that there was an issue with the file pathing, so there were a few things going wrong. Thank you for your time, I appreciate it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Amandio have a good day.